# C++: Cant't delete sqlite file after closing

Tags: c++, sqlite

I wrote a sqlite class with these functions:

```
bool Csqlite::init (string _InFile)
{
    if (sqlite3_open_v2(_InFile.c_str (), &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL) == SQLITE_ERROR)
         return false;

    return true;
}

void Csqlite::quit ()
{
    sqlite3_reset (stmt);
    sqlite3_clear_bindings (stmt);

    sqlite3_close(db);
}

bool Csqlite::execute (string _InOperation)
{
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2 (db, _InOperation.c_str (), _InOperation.size () + 1, &stmt, NULL) != 0)
        return false;

    if (sqlite3_step (stmt) == SQLITE_ERROR)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Now, the weird thing is, that if I call `init`, and without calling something else `quit`, than I can delete the local file in windows. But when I call `execute` between these 2 functions, and again trying to delete the file, Windows says that the file is sill opened.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to free the statement with [sqlite3_finalize](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html).